# What is the state of the art in the field of NLP?

Tags: nlp

I am new to Natural Language Processing, I think NLP is a challenging field, the syntax and semantic ambiguities could cause a lot of problems. For example I think for these problems machine translation is a hard task.

Therefore there are probably many approaches and methods that have been applied to this field. But what are the latest and most promising approaches and methods in the field of NLP?

Are these techniques highly dependent on the target language?

Comment: Opinion based posts are off topic here. This site is for discussing solutions to specific technical problems.

Comment: state of the art is the most advances in the field and are not opinion based, its based on history of that field.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably aware that deep learning is all the rage these days, and it has touched NLP too. There is a tutorial on it from a recent conference: [Deep Learning for Natural Language Processing (without Magic)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/courses/NAACL2013/) by Richard Socher and Christopher Manning, who are from Stanford.

Answer (score 2):

NLP is very vast and varied. Here are a few basic tools in NLP:

1. Sentence splitting: Identifying sentence boundaries in text
2. Tokenization: Splitting a sentence into individual words
3. Lemmatization: Converting a word to its root form. E.g. says, said,
   saying will all map to root form - say
4. Stemmer: It is similar to a
   lemmatizer, but it stems a word rather than get to the root form.
   e.g. laughed, laughing will stem to laugh. However, said, saying
   will map to sa - which is not particularly enlightening in terms of
   what "sa" means
5. POS tagger: Tags a word with the Part of Speech - what is a noun, verb, preposition etc.
6. Parser: Links words with POS tags to other words with POS tags. E.g. John ate an apple. Here John and apple are nouns linked by the verb - eat. John is the subject of the verb, and apple is the object of the verb.

If you are looking for the state of the art for these tools, check out [StanfordCoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml), which has most of these tools and a trained model to identify the above from a document. There is also an online demo to check out stanfordCoreNLP before downloading and using it with your application.

NLP has several subfields. Here are a few of them:

1. Machine Translation: Automatic Translation from one language to another
2. Information Retrieval: Something like a search engine, that retrieves relevant information from a large set of documents based on a search query
3. Information Extraction: Extract concepts and keywords - such as names of people, locations, times, synonyms etc.
4. Deep Learning has lately become a new field of NLP, where a system tries to understand a document like a human understands it.